# How extensive was the Allies use of inflatable decoy tanks during D-Day preparations?

Tags: world-war-two

I have seen in a couple WW2 documentaries, that inflatable decoy tanks were used during d-day preparations to fool the German military.

How extensive was this use? How many inflatable tanks were manufactured? How many were deployed at once in view? I can only ever find a video of one or two inflatable tanks at once.

Is there any media of there actually been a sizable amount of these deployed at once?

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article on [Operation Quicksilver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Quicksilver_(deception_plan)) which was part of Operation Fortitude. The article notes that "Contrary to a widespread misconception, the FUSAG deception was not primarily implemented with dummy tanks, airplanes, landing-craft, or other dummy equipment. It relied mainly on deception via wireless-telegraphy." It might be worth looking at the [Ghost Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Army) that operated after D-Day.

Comment: Complementing: [the XX system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-Cross_System) meant that the chance that nazi spies in England would personally see the inflatables was relatively small. Also, by 1944 there were still german reconnaissance flights over England, but not a lot of german combat planes as in 1940. So it was reasonable to expect relatively few inflatables to fool the reconnaissance planes and photograph analysts if smartly placed. And the deception really needs to be 3D to fool a pro aerial photo analyst, as they look for coherent shadows or may use stereoscopy.